# Need help understanding singletons and object life cycle

Tags: oop, singleton

If I have class with two methods, that do different things, but class properties are not changed each time I call these methods, is that class a good candidate to be a singleton ?

For example:

```
class Foo {

    public function doFirst($params);

    public function doSecond();

}
```

If I call doFirst() method in my controller, and doSecond() in my view. Does it make sense for this class to be a singleton ? What I am thinking is this: if I do not change the class properties ( the class state ), then I do not need two instances of it. Is this correct way of thinking ? Also, singleton classes can be configured only once, right ? So if I configure my class once and then call 2 of its methods, it can be a singleton. But if I need to reconfigure the class before calling second method it can not be singleton ?

I hope that you understand my question, because I am so confused and do not know how to ask it better.

Comment: I'd just pass the object on to the view from the controller.

Comment: That was just simple example, I am not solving that. My question is about singletons and object life cycle. The view where I am calling doSecond do not necessarily belong to the controller where I called doFirst

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to think that as long as methods are not mutating the state, or only one state is needed, a class can be a singleton.

However, the aim of the singleton pattern is used to create a globally mutable state, [which is already quite "code-smelly" on its own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons). If your state is immutable, then `static` (or `Shared` in VB) members will do just fine.

If your `Foo` class only has those two methods, I would mark them as `static` (or `Shared` in VB). Because they seem to just be "helper" methods that does not need any "state" to function.

If you want to mutate the state before calling the second method, I would suggest you use another pattern like [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) instead of singleton.

Comment: Thank you, I understand what you say. What if I want to create object that is not mutable, but I want to use DI Container, so that I can "instantiate" only interface throughout my code, so I can change implementation easy. Does that make any sense ?

Comment: @Anita That's ok. Use DI then.